# $r^\rho \log 2 r \le c r^s$ for some $c>0$ if $\rho<s$.

Tags: analysis, inequality

Let $0<\rho<s$ and $r>0$. I have the following inequality given which I cannot establish.

$$r^\rho \log 2 r \le c r^s$$ for some $c>0$.

How do we get this inequality?

Comment: that can be derived from the fact $\log(x) = o(x^t)$, for any $t > 0$, when $x \to \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to this exercise is to make appropriate reductions.

(1) Dividing both sides by $r^\rho$ and replacing $x := 2r$, we see that it is sufficient to show that $\log x \le c x^a$ for some constant $c := c_a$ and any $a > 0$.

(2) Replacing $y := x^a$, using the fact that $\log(y^{1/a}) = (\log y)/a$, this is equivalent to $\log y \le c y$ for some constant $c$.

(3) But we know that $\log y \le y$ for all $y \ge 1$, and so we are done.